# Checkmarx Cross-Site-Scripting improper sanitization or validation for user input for the params element in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, xss, joi, checkmarx

I'm trying to do resolve the checkmarx scan report for my code.
The error says something like:

> Method `async` at line 32 of `Controller\criteriaController.js` gets user input for the params element.
> This element’s value then flows through the code without being properly sanitized or validated and is eventually displayed to the user in method `async` at line 37 of `Controller\criteriaController.js`.
> This may enable a *Cross-Site-Scripting* attack.

I am using `celebrate` package and properly doing validation using `Joi` and `celebrate` methods.

I am not able to resolve this, kindly help me for some insights.
Below are my code snippets:

```js
exports.createSettings = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { auth, params, body } = req;
    const { userId } = auth || {};
    const { appId, projectId, settingId } = params || {};
    const { appClientId, type } = body;
    await processCreation({ appId, projectId, settingId, body, userId });
    res.send({
      status: 'Success',
      code: 200,
      data: await retrievePlans({
        appId,
        projectId,
        appClientId,
        type,
      }),
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    next(err);
  }
};
```

This is my route:

```js
route.post(
    '/:appId',
    checkSession,
    celebrate(createPlanSchema.appSchema),
    createPlanSettings,
);
```

This is `appSchema`

```js
exports.createPlanCriteriaSchema = {
  clientOnlySchema: {
    params: Joi.object({
      appId: Joi.number().required(),
    }),
    body: Joi.object({
      appId: Joi.number().allow(null, '').empty(['', null]),
      projectId: Joi.number().allow(null, '').empty(['', null]),
      appClientId: Joi.number().allow(null, '').empty(['', null]).default(2),
      type: Joi.number().allow(null, '').empty(['', null]).default(3)
    }),
  },
}
```

Comment: What dose the method "retrievePlans" do? It might be useful if you added that.

Comment: @n3018, I don't think Checkmarx recognizes Joi as a sanitizer. You will have to override the XSS Checkmarx query using Cx Audit to include the Joi validator